# Deploy Crystal reports to Dev/Test server

Tags: deployment, crystal-reports, report

When deploying ASP.Net solution that has crystal reports in some pages, what are the software that need to be installed for Crystal Reports? Do we have to manually copy reports to development server? or do we have any Report Manager like SSRS

Is there good site that gives information to deploy crystal reports in asp.net?

Thanks in advance

Comment: once you will publish the code all files will be copied, so no need to use any external software. but you need to make sure you have installed crystal report on your server

Comment: Thanks for the response, install crystal reports on server means what exactly we should be instaling on server like can you please name those components?